# Redshift ODBC Errors

Tags: ssis, odbc, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift ODBC 32-bit drivers to pull data in SQL-2016 via SSIS 2015 ODBC Connection. I have huge amount of data to be loaded from Redshift. I loaded about top 10000000 reocords in 21 mins.

However, my historical table has 260636061 records. If I run package to load all data, then it runs for some time and throws the following error -

**[ODBC Source [2]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY000'. Native Error Code: 30. [Amazon][RedShift ODBC] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: server closed the connection unexpectedly.This probably means the server terminated abnormallybefore or while processing the request.**

**[ODBC Source [2]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY001'. Native Error Code: 10010.[Amazon][ODBC] (10010) Memory allocation error: std::bad_alloc exception is caught.**

**[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().  The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.**

Any idea how to resolve this issue? OR shouldn't we pull this much data at once from SSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the driver is attempting to load all result rows into memory at once, whereas ideally it would send rows in batches, allowing SSIS to process them one batch at a time.

Try playing around with the options on your ODBC driver as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-options.html and see what works.

Is your driver set up as a DSN on your server, or is there an SSIS Source that can talk to it directly?  If it's a DSN, you'll see an "Additional Options" panel like the below that you can use:
[image: System DSN configuration]

If it's an SSIS source, the options will likely be available on the Connection Manager in SSIS.

Comment: Had this same error with SSIS when loading from a postgres database, and this solved it for me as well.